# Nearby cycles morphism of Guibert-Loeser-Merle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vanishing-cycles, nearby-cycles

In the paper *Iterated vanishing cycles, convolution, and a motivic analogue of a conjecture of Steenbrink* by Gil Guibert, Francois Loeser and Michel Merle, the authors defined the morphism for which I temporarily call "virtual" nearby cycles morphism as follows.

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and $X$ be a variety (reduced + separated + of finite type over $k$) equipped with a morphism $f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_k^1$. There exists a unique $\mathscr{M}_k$-linear morphism
$$\psi_f: \mathscr{M}_X \longrightarrow \mathscr{M}_{X_{\sigma} \times_k \mathbb{G}_{m,k}}^{\mathbb{G}_{m,k}}$$
such that
$$\psi_{f}([U \longrightarrow X]) = p_{\sigma!}(\psi_{f \circ p,U}).$$
whenever $U/k$ smooth, $U \hookrightarrow Z \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} X$ is a compactification of $U$ over $X$ (which always exists thanks to Nagata), for notations:

- $\mathscr{M}_X = K_0(\mathrm{Var}_X)[\mathbb{A}_X^1]^{-1}$ is the usual Grothendieck ring of varieties.
- $\mathscr{M}_{X_{\sigma} \times_k \mathbb{G}_{m,k}}^{\mathbb{G}_{m,k}}$ ($X_{\sigma} = f^{-1}(0)$ is the special fiber) is defined similarly but we start with varieties endowed with some good actions of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$.
- $\psi_{f \circ p,U}$ is the nearby cycles defined as certain limit of the so-called motivic zeta function.

**First question**: *Does this nearby cycles morphism commute with direct image with compact support of a proper morphism?*

By using the definition of Guibert-Loeser-Merle solely, I see it is true trivially, just like its "non-virtual" analogue, namely, the $l$-adic nearby cycles functor (F. Bittner in a paper *On motivic zeta functions and the motivic nearby fiber* defined a similar morphism $\psi_f$ commuting with smooth pullback and proper direct image but she used different equivariant Grothendieck rings).

**Second question**: suppose that my first question is right, then let's have a paper *Singularités à l'infini et intégration motivique* by Michel Raibaut in which the author used $\psi_f$ to defined the so-called "motivic Milnor fiber at infinity". It goes as follows. We start with a morphism $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_k^1$ where $U/k$ is a smooth, connected variety. Thanks to Nagata, we have a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @>{j}>> X;\\
@V{f}VV @V{\hat{f}}VV \\
\mathbb{A}_k^1 @>>> \mathbb{P}^1_k = \mathbb{A}_k^1 \sqcup \infty;
\end{CD}$$
with $j$ dense open immersion, $\hat{f}$ proper. **The motivic Milnor fiber at infinity** is defined to be
$$\hat{f}_{\sigma!}\psi_{1/\hat{f}}([U \setminus U_{\sigma}])$$
where $1/\hat{f}: X \setminus X_{\sigma} \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_k^1$ since we have removed the fiber at infinity so we can invert it. The first part of this work is devoted to proving the independence of the choice of compactification of this Milnor fiber. But if my first question is true, isn't it redundant since
$$\hat{f}_{\sigma!}\psi_{1/\hat{f}} \simeq \psi_{\mathrm{id}}1/\hat{f}$$
and so it is independent *à priori*?